# App inventor 2: How to split at spaces

Tags: android, string, split, app-inventor

I have a small question. I want to split the text at the space.

eg:

> "Hello World "

should be

> "Hello" ,"World"

I tried to use `"\r"` ,but it is no use. I don't know what can I do.

Please help me. Thank you very much.
I try 2 way to split the text. 
But the list length always 1.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please post the code snippet you tried

Comment: Marked up the input and output

Answer (score 1):

You can use [String.split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))

```
String yourString = "Hello World";

String[] result = yourString.split(" ");
result[0]; //"Hello"
result[1]; //"World"
```

Answer (score 1):

Why you need to use add item to list? Just use split at space function or split text at. Below is example of code. The result of length of list is 2:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

what about using the **[split at spaces](http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/ai2/support/blocks/text.html#splitatspaces)** block?

[image]

> Divides the given text at any occurrence of a space, producing a list
>   of the pieces.

A very good way to learn App Inventor is to read the free Inventor's Manual here in the AI2 free online eBook   http://www.appinventor.org/book2 ... the links are at the bottom of the Web page.  The book 'teaches' users how to program with AI2 blocks.
There is a free programming course here http://www.appinventor.org/content/CourseInABox/Intro  and the aia files for the projects in the book are here:  http://www.appinventor.org/bookFiles
How to do a lot of basic things with App Inventor are described here:  http://www.appinventor.org/content/howDoYou/eventHandling  .

Also do the tutorials http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/ai2/tutorials.html to learn the basics of App Inventor, then try something and follow the
 [Top 5 Tips: How to learn  App Inventor](https://puravidaapps.com/learn.php)